# .net-core3.1 on Visual Studio for Mac: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint

Tags: macos, visual-studio, ssl, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

On my Mac, Visual Studio throws this error when I try to run a .net core project.

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint.
> No server certificate was specified, and the default developer
> certificate could not be found or is out of date.\nTo generate a
> developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the
> certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https
> --trust'.\nFor more information on configuring HTTPS see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.%22)

Running: `dotnet dev-certs https`

Returns:

> A valid HTTPS certificate with a key accessible across security
> partitions was not found. The following command will run to fix it:
> 'sudo security set-key-partition-list -D localhost -S
> unsigned:,teamid:UBF8T346G9' This command will make the certificate
> key accessible across security partitions and might prompt you for
> your password. For more information see:
> https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/2.1/troubleshootcertissues A valid HTTPS
> certificate with a key accessible across security partitions was not
> found. The following command will run to fix it: 'sudo security
> set-key-partition-list -D localhost -S unsigned:,teamid:UBF8T346G9'
> This command will make the certificate key accessible across security
> partitions and might prompt you for your password. For more
> information see: https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/3.1/troubleshootcertissues
> A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.

Running: `sudo security set-key-partition-list -D localhost -S unsigned:,teamid:UBF8T346G9`

Prompts for two passwords:

> Password:
>
> password to unlock default:

and then returns:

> security: SecKeychainItemSetAccessWithPassword: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.

I have also deleted my `localhost` certificate and generated a new one.

What else should I try?

Comment: Did you try running: `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` and then `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`?

Comment: Hey @MattWard - yes I did... still no luck :-(

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

- Open Keychains
- Click on System / Certificates
- find the cert for localhost
- right click and delete
- go to your terminal enter dotnet dev-certs https --trust